# Парсинг таблиц с сайта

Tags: python

Хотел спарсить данные с сайта Мосбиржи, но на начальном этапе написания парсера увидел, что эту таблицу как бы и не видно по ссылке на выбранный иструмент, помогите понять, как забрать нужные данные!

```
**import requests
import fake_useragent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
header = {'user-agent': user}
link = "https://www.moex.com/ru/issue.aspx?board=TQCB&code=RU000A107C34&utm_source=www.moex.com&utm_term=RU000A107C34#/bond_1"
responce = requests.get(link, headers = header).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce, 'lxml')
param = soup.find_all('table')
print(param)**
```

Ответ:

```
*[<table class="market-table__content">
<thead>
<tr class="market-table__row _nobg">
<th class="market-table__cell _head" title="Тип параметра">Тип параметра</th>
<th class="market-table__cell _head" title="Значение">Значение</th>
<th class="market-table__cell _head"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="market-table__row">
<td class="market-table__cell">Доходность</td>
<td class="market-table__cell">19.56%</td>
<td class="market-table__cell"><span class="market-table__sol-caller">?<span class="market-table__sol-body _right">Доходность по цене последней сделки</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="market-table__row">
<td class="market-table__cell">Дата погашения</td>
<td class="market-table__cell">21.11.2026</td>
<td class="market-table__cell"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="market-table__row">
<td class="market-table__cell">Дата, к которой рассчитывается доходность</td>
<td class="market-table__cell">–</td>
<td class="market-table__cell"><span class="market-table__sol-caller">?<span class="market-table__sol-body _right">Если данное поле не заполнено,  «Доходность посл. сделки» рассчитывается к Дате погашения</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="market-table__row">
<td class="market-table__cell"><b>Сумма купона </b></td>
<td class="market-table__cell"><b>14.79</b></td>
<td class="market-table__cell"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="market-table__row">
<td class="market-table__cell">Дата выплаты купона</td>
<td class="market-table__cell">05.04.2024</td>
<td class="market-table__cell"><span class="market-table__sol-caller">?<span class="market-table__sol-body _right">Дата выплаты купона</span></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>]*
```

[image: То,что видит парсер с сайта]

[image: То, что хочется запарсить]

Comment: [Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/749943/178576)

Answer (score 0):

Для этого сайта нужно найти запрос https://iss.moex.com/iss/reference/, составить ссылку, забрать ответ.

Comment: Извините, новичек совсем в этом, не смог разобраться, какую именно ссылку следует взять. Не поможете, хотя бы намеком, как искать?

Comment: Я посмотрел в "Сети" ответы, но что есть что не слог разобраться